# How to add the User:Picture field on the account registration form?

Tags: entities, users

I saw the User:Picture field after setting the User:uid contextual filter for a Views block. Now I am wondering how to show this field on the account registration form? I looked at config/people/accounts/fields but nothing there.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Register with Picture](https://www.drupal.org/project/reg_with_pic) module.

> This module exposes the 'upload picture' element to the registration
>   form. It also gives you the ability to set a picture as required in
>   the module settings.
>
> Drupal 7 Instructions
>
> 1. Install and enable the module
> 2. Navigate to: Configuration -> Account Settings. (admin/config/people/accounts)
> 3. Check Enable user pictures if it isn't checked already.
> 4. Confirm Enable pictures on registration is checked.
> 5. Use the Registration Picture Field Weight field to adjust the display order of the picture field on the registration form. It can be
>      a negative or positive number.